# Find in two array and show the found one

Tags: mongodb

I have docs like this one:

```
{
    up: [],
    down: []
}
```

`up` and `down` contain ids of users which are unique and can be only in one of the arrays.

Is it possible to find an id in the arrays and return in which one an id was found?

Comment: Could you please elaborate your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could run the following aggregation pipeline:

```
db.collection.aggregate({
    $project: {
        "foundIn": {
            $cond: [
                // if the filtered "up" array does not equal an empty array []
                { $in: [ userId, "$up" ] },
                // then return "up"
                "up",
                {
                    // otherwise we apply the same logic for "down"
                    $cond: [
                        { $in: [ userId, "$down" ] },
                        "down",
                        // fall back to "nowhere" result if the searched value is not contained in either array
                        "nowhere"
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve by following way:

```
db.collection.find().forEach(function(doc){
     var num=2; 
     if(doc.up.indexOf(num)>-1) 
         print("found in up"); 
     else if(doc.down.indexOf(num)>-1) 
         print("found in down"); 
     else 
         print("not found") 
})
```